# If flux is number of electric field lines passing through a surface or 3D figure, that means it is a number so why it is not dimensionless?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

My teacher said that electrostatic flux is the number of electric field lines passing through a surface or a 3-dimensional figure, and explained its mathematical expression as $Φ = ES\cosθ$. However,I am thinking that if it is the number of electric field lines passing through , then it must be dimensionless, then why flux have dimensions?

Comment: Please take a look here : [ACuriousMind](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/50583/acuriousmind). Although not mandatory, you must think to change a little your username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

``Number of field lines" is a figure of speech. It is not supposed to be taken literally.

Flux is a closed surface area integral, so it is area units multiplied by the units of the vector field you are integrating over. Here, you are talking about Electric field, so it has to have to units of electric field multiplied by area units.

Answer (score 1):

Because your teacher is not giving you the full picture.
$$
||\mathbf E||\cdot||\mathbf S||\cos{\theta}=\Phi
$$
This formula, gives you the flux , but does not give you a complete insight and understanding of what "amount of lines passing through a surface" is.

The electric field is a vector field. A vector field, is a mathematical function that assigns an arrow (vector) to each point of space. How many points are in space? Infinite. So saying flux is the amount of vectors (or lines, formed by following those vectors) passing through a surfaces is a vague explanation.

You could understand it better if you think of flux as how much the vector field points in the direction of the surfaces normal vector (a vector perpendicular to the surface) and it strength (the norm of the vector).

[image]

If the arrows (or lines) are penpendicular to the surface, you will have more flux and the other way arround (that's why you have $\cos \theta$ on your formula). And, also, the longer the arrows passing through the surface and the bigger your surface is, the more flux you have (that's why you have $||\mathbf E||$ and $||\mathbf S||$ on your formula).

In mathematics a vector field is dimensionless. In phyisics, you have dimensions and magnitudes that help you measure real life phemomena. In this case, because you have a product of the electric field and the surface, now your quantity have dimensions, $(\frac{N \cdot m^2}{C})$.